# Non-Clickable Menu Items

Tags: 8, navigation

In a Drupal 8 site, I want to add menu items with "no link", I was thinking that nolink is allowed but when I entered this, I got error

> Manually entered paths should start with /, ? or #.

Is there a way for adding menu items not clickable without adding "#" because "#" add attribute [data-drupal-link-system-path=""] and [class="is-active"]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to use `route:<nolink>` to achieve this. Then it will validate and render without a link.

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried it and it working fine, but still adding attributes of [ data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>" ] and [ class="is-active" ]

Comment: That is a separate issue from what you're trying to achieve and either a core bug or problem with your theme, but `route:<nolink>` is definitely the answer. It even works with Pathauto.

Comment: The "is-active" class bug has been reported here: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2838351

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for such a knowledgeable solution.

Comment: +1 upvote - thank you - `<nolink>` works when adding link in standard Drupal menu, `admin/structure/menu/manage/main/add` so that you can have other words on menu, perhaps to go before a set of links that have similar purpose, e.g. social links (using [menu_link_attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes) & [fontawesome_menu_icons](https://drupal.org/project/fontawesome_menu_icons) modules. Then also add `nth` child css and the menu can be positioned separately from other links. [menu_export](https://drupal.org/project/menu_export) is handy for putting menu items into config.

Comment: Mind you, I got this error after saving the non-clickable link as per my suggestion "Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in Drupal\content_sync\Normalizer\ContentEntityNormalizer->getMenuLinkNodeAttached() (line 156 of modules/contrib/content_sync/src/Normalizer/ContentEntityNormalizer.php)."  - this might be specific to my setup but just to note that my suggestion might have issues.

Comment: I think in D9 it is just <nolink> now.

Answer (score 5):

To create a menu item without link in a custom module add to [module_name].links.menu.yml:

`url: 'internal:##'`

You need to add a second # character (or any other letter or word `url: 'internal:#nolink'`) in order to the href attribute will not rendered empty, which will cause a page reload if the user click the link.

Comment: This is a good solution also. For me better than remove the link, that removes the <a> tag and then this menu item loose the corresponding css styles.

Answer (score 2):

- https://www.drupal.org/project/link_attributes
- or https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes

and add class or style for item [a style="pointer-events:none; cursor:default; text-decoration:none;" ...][/a]

```
pointer-events:none; cursor:default; text-decoration:none;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 you can create a link programmatically using Link::fromTextAndUrl not linkable like that:

```
$my_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('This is my link text'), Url::fromUri('route:<nolink>'));
```

Optionally you can convert it to an array using: `$my_link = $my_link->toRenderable();`